# Matrix differential equation with inequality, $ y'(t) \leq A y(t) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I have an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and a system of ODEs of the form 
$$ y'(t) = A y(t) + b(t) $$
Where $b(t) \leq 0$ such that $$ y'(t) \leq A y(t) \qquad (1)$$
I also know that $y(t) \geq 0$. 
Is is correct to conclude from $(1)$ that 
$ 0 \leq y(t) \leq c_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}}u_{1} + ... + c_{n}e^{\lambda_{n}}u_{n} $  where $\lambda_{i}$ and $u_{i}$ are respectively the corresponding eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $A$?
I know that this should hold with equalities instead of inequalities but I am not sure if it does in this case as well (assuming $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors).